# .NET Validator (Image Trigger)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, validation

I have a web form with 1 textbox, a required field validator for it & a send button.
When everything is okay the validator isn't triggered and I present a "Success" image to the user. If I try to send another thing & the validator is triggered it won't enter the back-code of the button (to hide the "Success" image till the validator passes).

What should I write in the back-code / .net to hide the "Success" image while the validator is being shown?

Tnx!

Comment: `back-code` = `codebehind`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yeah :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use javascript to hide the success image if validation fails, e.g.:

```
function btnSendClientClick()
{
    var imgSuccess = document.getElementById('SuccessImage');
    Page_ClientValidate();  
    for(i=0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++)
    {
        if(!Page_Validators[i].isvalid)
        {
            imgSuccess.style.display='none';
            return;
        }
    }     
}

<asp:button id="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Send" 
    onClientClick="btnSendClientClick()" />
```

Comment: Tnx, it helped me a lot :)